# How to find if an Integer has letters in its hex representation

Tags: c++, stream

I am trying to write a method in C++ which determines if an integer has letters in its hex representation using stream manipulators without using any for loop.
One way could be to use `getline` and do some math. Can someone provide hints on the kind of computation required?

I appreciate your helps or using the Circular Arithmetic , But I am looking for something which does not iterate over the string

Comment: Im not sure, but if you think about it: letters are usually only used to represent 10, 11, 12,13,14,15 (A,B,C,D,E,F). Maybe it is a good idea to devide your integer somehow with mod operator?

Comment: What kind of stream, is it binary stream, character stream or stream of bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do someting like (only logic operation and one substraction)

```
 bool has_letters(int num)
 {   
      if(num < 0) num = 0- num; //abs value
      unsigned char * c;
      c = (unsigned char * )(& num)
      for(int i=0;i<sizeof(int),i++)
      {
           if(((c[i] & 0xf) > 0x9) || ((((c[i]>>4) & 0xf) > 0x9) )
               return true;
           //or you can use precomputed table
           //if(table[c[i]])
           //     return true;
      }
      return false;
 }
```

Trick is that binary representaion of string is allready hex (almost) you just need to chek each [nibble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble)

Comment: I think you have made an assumption about size of unsigned char and size of integer

Comment: Can i assume that sizeof(char) == 1 and 8 bits and number_of_bits(int) % 8 == 0 ?

Answer (score 6):

Using C++ `ostringstream` and `string`:

```
bool hasHexDigits(int number)
{
    std::ostringstream output;
    output << std::hex << number;
    return output.str().find_first_of("abcdefABCDEF") != string::npos;
}
```

EDIT: other solution, without using streams. It's better performance (no branches) and memory wise (no allocations), but may be too advanced for your "homework":

```
template<int I> struct int_to_type
{
    static const int value = I;
};

inline bool __hasHexCharacters(int number, int_to_type<0>)
{
    return false;
}

template <int digitsLeft>
inline bool __hasHexCharacters(int number, int_to_type<digitsLeft>)
{
   return ((number & 0xF) > 9) | __hasHexCharacters(number >> 4, int_to_type<digitsLeft-1>());
}

inline bool hasHexCharacters(int number)
{
    return __hasHexCharacters(number, int_to_type<2 * sizeof(int)>());
}
```

Comment: @gwaiazdorr This is not my Homework ! I am trying to do self study of this course reader http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/course_reader.html  .. I will get into templates soon

Comment: @raikrahul: You should stick to the first solution then - it is slow, but it is C++ idmiomatic. So, first learn the language culture, then try to optimise (vide my second solution).

Comment: @gwaiazdorr - Nope I did not, and in fact after reading his requirements I removed it as I thought it wasn't relevant, didn't see your reply at that point :)

Answer (score 5):

divide the int by 16 until you reach zero. Each time check the remainder, if it is > 9 hex contains letters.

Comment: Ya , I can get the circular mod operator

Answer (score 2):

```
sprintf(string,"%x",<your integer>);
```

will give your hexa decimal number.

so after this,check if your string has any alphabets below using some string functions available.

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Assumes 32-bit int. Computing the mask based on UINT_MAX is left as an
// exercise for the reader.

int has_hex_alpha(unsigned int num) {
    return !!((num & (num << 1 | num << 2)) & 2290649224);
}
```

Comment: <<i means to append #i zeros. That cryptic number is a String of 1000 or 8 s . |ing the two to get a mask , and then &ing with those 1000 series will always tell you if any "part" of the Num =>1010. !! means ~~ | !! .  Exercise Done !!

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are very weird, so it's hard to give a correct answer. All the solutions so far seems to either iterate ( although some inside std functions ), or work with a straight up integer, which seems to go against your requirements? "hex representation" suggests to me that you have the number in the form of a string. If this is the fact then not using for loops(?) & forcing us to use stream manipulators makes it a no go. If the representation is in form of a ascii string, and we're not allowed to iterate, then one solution which doesn't require neither iteration nor  conversion ( which likely will iterate in itself ) can make use of the fact that all alpha numeric chars have at least one of the 2 MSBs set:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include "boost\cstdint.hpp"
union StrInt
{
    boost::uint64_t val;
    char str[ sizeof( boost::uint64_t ) ];
};

int main()
{
    std::string someString("A9999999" );
    StrInt tmp;
    assert( someString.size() <= sizeof( tmp.str ) );
    memcpy( tmp.str, &someString[0], someString.size() );
    std::cout << !!( tmp.val & 0xC0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0ul ) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use regex?

```
regex rgx("[A-Za-z]+");
smatch result;    
if(regex_search(integer_string, result, rgx)) { 
  cout << "There is alpha chars in the integer string" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool func(int num) {
    while ( num > 0 ) {
         if ( num % 16 > 9 ) return true;
         num /= 16;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This math is obvious.But the problem is that taking a number dividing by 16 {10000} , then checking for 9 ::I needed something exclusively from stream manipulation

Answer (score 1):

Another method using stringstream:

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::string str;
std::string::iterator it;
bool hasChar = false;

// Use the hex modifier to place the hex representation of 75 into the
// stream and then spit the hex representation into a string.
ss << std::hex << 75;
str = ss.str(); // str contains "4b"
it = str.begin();

// Check for characters in hex representation.
while (!hasChar && it != str.end())
{
    if (isalpha(*it))
        hasChar = true;
    ++it;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the stream manipulators, something like:

```
bool
hasAlphaInRepresentation( unsigned number )
{
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << std::hex << number;
    std::string str = s.str();
    return std::find( str.begin(), str.end(), IsAlpha()) != str.end();
}
```

would do the trick.  (I'm assuming that you have an IsAlpha functional 
object in your toolbox.  If not, it's fairly straightforward to
implement, and it's always useful.)

Of course, if the only requirement were no loop:

```
bool
hasAlphaInRepresentation( unsigned number )
{
    return number != 0
        && (number % 16 > 9 || hasAlphaInRepresentation( number / 16 ));
}
```

:-)

Comment: It was meant more as a joke.  In this case, the obvious solution (and also IMHO the best) is a loop: `while ( number != 0 && number % 16 < 10 ) { number /= 16; } return number != 0;`  But the requirements said...  (Come to think of it, they said "no for loop"; the above doesn't have a for loop, but a while loop.  But there was also a bit about using a stream.)

Answer (score 0):

You can first store a hex representation in the stringstream and try to convert it to a decimal representation. If it fails to convert, then we can say that letters are present in the given integer

```
    stringstream myStream;
    int myInt;
    cin>>myInt;
    myStream<<hex<<myInt;
    myStream>>dec>>myInt;
    cout<<myStream.fail()<<endl;
```